# Postgres Parse String with Delimiter

Tags: regex, postgresql

Trying to parse a sting using SQL, and have not found any solutions online (apologies, maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing).

I have a string field with a series of numbers I need to pull out and sum. Delimiter is "\r\n".

Example: '\r\n - 1234 somenumbersandtext123 \r\n -5678 sometextmorenumbers123'

So in this example, I want to sum 1234 and 5678.

The stings are all different lengths, and I need to eventually sum the numbers within the string. The string details documents tied to a project, and the numbers represent the size of the file (trying to determine the total file size per project).

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Here's what I have so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/73df7/1 using `regexp_split_to_table`

Comment: If you need to sum all numbers in the particular string: `with t(x) as (values('- 232554 /sometext.pdf\r\n- 27491.70 /morewords\r\n- 138283 /filename.pdf\r\n'))
select n[1]::numeric from t, regexp_matches(x,'\d+\.?\d*','g') as n;`

Comment: @Abelisto thanks for the response. I should have noted, my text strings can contain numbers, so I'm not simply looking to sum all numbers within the string. I only want to sum the numbers that come after my "\r\n". Updated example string in the OP.

Comment: Ok, try this pattern: `'\\r\\n[^\d]*(\d+\.?\d*)'`

Comment: @Abelisto awesome, thanks!

Comment: Try `regexp_matches(col,'(?:^|\n)\s*-\s*(\d*\.?\d+)','g')`. If `\n` in the input is a 2 char combination, replace `\n` with `\\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
regexp_matches(col,'(?:^|\n)\s*-\s*(\d*\.?\d+)','g')
```

The part captured with `(...)` will be the output of the `regexp_matches` function.

**Details**

- `(?:^|\n)` - start of string or newline
- `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Capturing group 1 (what will be returned):

  - `\d*` - 0+ digits
  - `\.?` - 1 or 0 dots
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

`SELECT 
REGEXP_MATCHES(
  string::text
  ,'\Br\Bn ?- ?([0-9]+)',
        'g')
from test_table`