# Find max numerical value nested in a string column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres database. This database has a table `my_table` with a column `log`.
The `log` column stores a string of a violation of some bounds.
So the log can look something like:

```
bounds exceeded. bounds_limit : {amount:4 freq:5}, actual : {amount:5 freq:1}
```

I want to extract the max value of the `actual` `amount` over all rows.

Comment: You have a PostgreSQL database. psql is just a terminal-based front-end to PostgreSQL. It enables you to type in queries interactively, issue them to PostgreSQL, and see the query results.

Comment: Try with regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700582/postgres-parse-string-with-delimiter

Comment: Is this **exactly** how that log appears in the table? This looks like psuedo-json, which is kind of the worst of both worlds. If in reality it is well formed json, postgres has functionality for that which won't rely on brittle regex.

Comment: If you like parsing butchered json with regex, you'll also love this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/939860

Answer (score 1):

Extract the actual amount value from `log` using `substring` with a regular expression, cast it to `numeric` and select `max` of the resulting value. `my_table` CTE is a mimic of an actual table.

```sql
with my_table(log) as (
 values
 ('bounds exceeded. bounds_limit : {amount:4 freq:5}, actual : {amount:5 freq:1}'), 
 ('bounds exceeded. bounds_limit : {amount:6 freq:7}, actual : {amount:7 freq:3}'),
 ('bounds exceeded. bounds_limit : {amount:5 freq:6}, actual : {amount:6 freq:2}')
)
select max(substring(log from 'actual\s*:\s*\{amount:(.+)\s+.*\}')::numeric)
from my_table;
```

The result is 7.
However as @Error_2646 noted if `log` contains well formed JSON then the query would be trivial and far more performant and reliable.